# Assigning UISearchBar Text Property does not trigger TextChanged Event

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

whenever user types text in searchbar , web request is triggered  this is done by C# RX (by Observable )

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<UISearchBarTextChangedEventArgs>(ev => searchBar.TextChanged += ev,
                    ev => searchBar.TextChanged -= ev)
```

the problem is that when i programmatically assign value to searchbar.Text property ,

```
searchBar.Text ="Not Triggered!"
```

event is not getting called, what can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is quite simple , you need to call UISearchBar's Delegate method like this

```
searchBar.Delegate.TextChanged(searchBar, searchBar.Text);
```